# Creating an Article-Posting Driven Website with Database to store website data

Tags: database, web, frontend, backend

I have this cool idea of a website/app where users can write and post articles and others can then comment, like, save posts, etc where all posts show up on a live feed which is the home page. Kind of like facebook but literally strictly limited to just writing articles.

Naturally, i designed the entire front end as i'm good with web design and functionalities using jquery and angular. Now i know i need to connect the website to a database to store all the articles/posts of every user, their account info, likes and comments of each post, etc. This is the part that i am new to. Can anyone explain detailed steps from A to Z on how to implement this type of backend i would need to achieve this idea? including how to connect the backend to the frontend.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Much too broad a question for Stack Overflow. This site is for narrowly-focused questions on a specific programming  problem where reasonable people can agree on a specific solution. Open-ended discussions are off-topic here.

Comment: i understand. so where can i ask this sort of question? Do you have any ideas where i can get even a lead?

Comment: There are many discussion sites where you might get guidance, such as http://www.CodeRanch.com/. And you can educate yourself by doing some blind searching on a search engine or in Stack Overflow.